# Difference between transform:translate3d(50%,0,0) and left:50% in css?

Tags: css, transform

How does the transform:translate3d(50%,0,0) differ from left:50% in css?
heres the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/svjnwme0/) that i made.

```
transform: translate3d(50%,0,0)
```

and

```
left:50%;
```

[image: figure]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`translate3d(50%,0,0)` considers the percentage as of the element itself, so it is being translated from the left half of the element size.

The left of the div that is positioned absolute in the fiddle is relative to the container div which is positioned relative, so the `left:50%;`is 50% of this container.

Answer (score 3):

`Left` value describes width related to parent element(or what it would be if `width :100%` was set)
`transform` values describe in relation to its own width
Since you have explicitly set a width, the 2 results are different