# Why we use translate:transform with left and right to center an element?

Tags: css

Why is it necessary to use `transform:translate` property with left and right to center an element? Can you please explain logically the role of `translate` property used below.

This is the approach I have picked from the internet, but I’m not able to understand what’s happening with the code - i.e how it implements logically and whats the need of `translate:transform` and what role it play in the below.

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Output is ok, but I’m not able to imagine the role `transform:translate` is playing here.

Comment: Because an element is placed using its top left corner. So to really center it, it is moved negatively half its width and height to the left top.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38842981/difference-between-transformtranslate3d50-0-0-and-left50-in-css
This might help.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#absolute {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#after-position {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#after-translate {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#center {
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  color:blue;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="absolute">Hello there1</div>
<div id="after-position">Hello there2</div>
<div id="after-translate">Hello there3</div>
<div id="center"></div>
```

I hope you're familiar with the co-ordinate positioning of CSS. Your top left corner is (0,0) and bottom right is the (maxX, maxY).

When you set the position to absolute, the element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element. When you set top and left to 50%. The left top corner of the bounding box of your element is placed at (midX, midY). As you wanted your center of bounding box of your element to be aligned with the center of web page, you translate your X and Y co-ordinates by 50% in the negative axes, so it is -50%.

See the live illustration in the example provided. Zoom into the top-left corner of the border of 2nd div. You can see the blue dot when center is located.